# How to check if the current process is the child of other process?

Tags: c++, process

I have a problem with forks and waitpids. If some fork is trying to waitpid on a non-child of his, it will display:

> waitpid failed: No child processes

If I have a `pid_t pidA`, how can I check if the current process is the parent process of `pidA`?

Comment: There's nothing in POSIX for that, this will have to be OS-dependent. On Linux one can read `/proc/<pid>/status`, and extract the PPid value.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you end up needing to find out. Can't you keep track of your own  child processes and check?